# Regex group without capturing

Tags: regex

I created a regex to parse the src-attribute (hosting the images now on cloudfront) and alt-attribute from images.
I'm substituting them to turn them into Markdown.

Some  are embedded into an  attribute. I created an optional group for the surrounding  `(<a href.*)?`
Since I use backreferences to create my Markdown I don't want these optional groups to be captured.
How can I do this?

This is my regex:

```
/(<a href.*)?<img.*?src="http:\/\/www.example.com\/uploads(.*?)" alt="(.*?)".*?\/?>(<\/a>)?/gm
```

This is my substituion:

```
![$2](http://example.cloudfront.net/images$1)
```

Comment: [Don't parse HTML with regex!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/418066)

Comment: ...but to answer your question: `(?:<a href.*)?`

Comment: In general I agree with @Biffen - it's a bad idea to parse html with regex, unless it's a known subset/source etc.  The keywords you're looking for here to find results are "non capturing groups"

Comment: I agree with @Biffen. But if you want group wthout capture use this syntax: (?: group content )

Comment: @Biffen I'm migrating my blog. Therefore I'm manually migrating the posts (to clean of dust etc.). I'm just using this regex to make the cumbersome image conversion a tad easier before pasting into my post editor.

Comment: Either answer the question so I can mark it as answered or I will delete it within a few hours (so people don't get the wrong idea about regex'ing HTML)

Comment: I don't see why you need to match the enclosing `<a>` element.  Those parts of your regex are optional, so they don't narrow down the possible matches at all.  Have you tried it without them?

Comment: @Hedge I think this question should be deleted. Parse html by regex is a doubtful idea and regex syntax documented good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agreed that parsing HTML with regex is not a nice idea. But since you are wanting to hand out some reputation points I'll be a cherry picker... :-)

```
/(?:<a href.*)?<img.*?src="http:\/\/www.example.com\/uploads(.*?)" alt="(.*?)".*?\/?>(?:<\/a>)?/gm
```

I will state again here at the end for clarity that parsing HTML with regex is not a good idea.

Comment: I'm not using that regex programmatically but just to convert HTML to markdown by hand.

Comment: Works for me - I'm almost at my 1000 level with your little boost! :-)